touching outside the navbar calls the click method
I have a problem with the navigation bar, if an element on the screen is not clickable, then when you click on it, the screen opens as if the click was made on the navigation bar from below. I used marginBottom on mycontainer screen.
    return (<Tab.Navigator
    tabBarStyle={{position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#F8F7FB',
    borderRadius: 30,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center'}}
    screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        activeTintColor: '#000000',
        activeBackgroundColor: '#E2E2E2',
        inactiveBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        labelStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'Rubik_400Regular',
            fontStyle: "bold",
            fontSize: 13,
            color: '#181725',
        },
    }}>
    <Tab.Screen
        name="ScreenTabMain"
        options={{

I try marginBottom and useBottomTabBarHeight() but not solved. This problem have on ios and android

Please [edit] your question to include a minimal reproducible example so that readers can run your code to answer your question.
